# How to push object data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object:

```
{background: "#f3f3f3", color: "#f435"}
```

And i have an array:

```
elData = {
   colors: [],
}
```

I want push object(key:val) to array.

**Finaly data should be:**

```
elData = {
   colors: [
     {background: "#f3f3f3"},
     {color: "#f435"}
   ],
}
```

how i can do that?

Comment: Please share what you've tried, or the research you've done. We prefer to help you out as opposed to write the code for you :) That said, what is this structure meant to accomplish? If `colors` isn't supposed to have duplicate keys, perhaps it's better as an object itself, instead of an array of single-property objects.

Comment: That's an odd result. You're taking the object apart and creating new objects for each property in the original. Look at `Object.entries`, `for-of`, and computed property notation. (Assuming an ES2015+ environment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to first break down the original object into new objects of its component parts. Then add each component part into a new object and push that onto the array inside of ElData

```js
oldObject = {background: "#f3f3f3", color: "#f435"}
colors=[];
elData = {
   colors: [],
}

Object.keys(oldObject).map(function(oldKey, index) {
    var value = oldObject[oldKey];
    newObject={};
    newObject={oldKey:value}
    elData.colors.push(newObject);
});



console.log(elData);

/*
elData = {
   colors: [
     {background: "#f3f3f3"},
     {color: "#f435"}
   ],
}
*/
```